# Where can I find some open datasets of biological data and biomedical informatics data?

Tags: data-request, medical, biology

I am looking for **open biological datasets** and open **open health informatics** datasets, to test some machine learning algorithms that I designed.

Specifically, I am looking for datasets in which each element has a binary **label** (e.g. true/false, dead/alive), or a real valued label (e.g. score=0.7/1), to run some supervised learning approaches.

Can anyone send me to any open datasets of this kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the University of California-Irvine (UCI)  [Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/).  On this landing page, there is a link out to all datasets on the upper right.